# Output HTML from an Aurelia TS variable into the view

Tags: typescript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have an Aurelia app that works something like so:

**test.ts**

```
private testing:string;

// The constructor and other methods get the testing from the database that contains clean/sanitized HTML (not malious or entered by a user)

// An example:
testing = "<i>Source:</i>This code is<br />old but it is okay.";
```

Then in the view I want to have the HTML render as opposed to the string.

**test.html**

```
<div>${testing}</div>
```

The issue is that the output on screen thus contains the `<i>`, `</i>`, and `<br />` tags but I want it to behave as normal HTML when it is rendered.

How is this accomplished in Aurelia? The data is safe (no script tags are ever included).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to the content of the div, you could bind to the inner html. This is done the following way:

```
<div innerHtml.bind="testing"></div>
```

Best wishes.

Cristian

Comment: The following way? I think some stuff is missing.